# Do AngularJS custom directives appear similar to HTML5 Semantic Tags to Search Engines?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, seo, semantic-markup

We all know that one of the greatest advantages of HTML5 Semantic Tags is SEO. But do SEOs consider all (read custom, non HTML5) tags to be semantic?

Let's say I am making an e-commerce portal that sells shoes with an AngularJS front end, and use an custom Angular directive like so:

```
<shoe name="adidas" class="{{shoeClass}}"></shoe>
```

I know that the `shoeClass` will be invisible to the Google bot because it won't exist before AngularJS is compiled, but the DOM itself does exist in the static HTML. Therefore, the `<shoe>` tag is certainly going to be visible to the bot.

But will the bot make any sense of this tag? Will this give me brownie points (considering all other aspects of SEO are taken care of, and I serve static pre-rendered pages using Meteor or PhantomJS)? Or will the bot discard the tag as gibberish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Google, it is likely to discard the tag, because Google focuses mostly on what is explicitly visible to users to establish relevancy and to compute rankings (there are small exceptions, but the SEO value of such 'content' is almost always demoted).

Moreover, if this technique worked, people could easily manipulate Google and Google hates that. It does all it can to avoid being influenced that way.

So, I would not count on SEO brownie points here.